# Scala interop with Java overriding method with Object

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have this Java interface

```
public interface IFoo {

    List<Map<String, Object>> getMaps() throws Exception;
}
```

**how can I override this method ?** i tried :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
class Foo extends IFoo{
 override def getMaps: util.List[util.Map[String,AnyRef]]  = {
    List(Map("A" -> "B")).asJava
  }
}
```

but I am getting this compilation error

> overriding method getMaps in trait IFoo of type
>   ()java.util.List[java.util.Map[String,Object]]; [ERROR]  method
>   getMaps has incompatible type

I can do something like :

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
class Foo extends IFoo{
 override def getMaps: util.List[util.Map[String,AnyRef]]  = {
    List(Map("A" -> "B".asInstanceOf[AnyRef)).asJava
  }
}
```

> But is it the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `Map` to a Java `Map` as well, and there is a better way to provide the value type:

```
List(Map[String, AnyRef]("A" -> "B").asJava).asJava
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your `overriding incompatible type` error. But I get `type mismatch` inside the method and that trouble is fixed in this answer.

```
class Foo extends IFoo{
  override def getMaps: util.List[util.Map[String,AnyRef]]  = {
    List(Map("A" -> "B").mapValues(x => x: AnyRef).asJava).asJava
  }
}
```